# How do I listen to all Seam contextual events with parameterized names?

Tags: events, seam, observer-pattern, jbpm

Seam will fire [different kinds of events](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/events.html#d0e5252) that relate to particular scopes, tasks, or processes and appends the name of the scope, task or process to the end of the event.

How do I listen to all the events of a type?

E.g. for any `<name>` I'd like to listen to events such as these:

- `org.jboss.seam.createProcess.<name>` — called when the process  is created
- `org.jboss.seam.endProcess.<name>` — called when the process  ends
- `org.jboss.seam.initProcess.<name>` — called when the process  is associated with the conversation
- `org.jboss.seam.startTask.<name>` — called when the task  is started
- `org.jboss.seam.endTask.<name>` — called when the task  is ended

I need to do this *despite not knowing the list of valid names* up front...  :-(

I hope to be using @Observer to create the observer, or something similar, and I'll listen to up to two event classes in the same component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this by replacing Seam's Events class with your own implementation.  Then look for events that are raised that start with a particular string:

```
@Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
@BypassInterceptors
@Name("org.jboss.seam.core.events")
@Install(precedence=APPLICATION)
public class Events extends org.jboss.seam.core.Events
{
   @Override
   public void raiseEvent(String type, Object... parameters )
   {
       super.raiseEvent( type, parameters );

       if ( type.startsWith( "org.jboss.seam.createProcess" ) )
       {
           super.raiseEvent( "org.jboss.seam.createProcess", parameters );
       }
       //etc.
   }
}
```

You can now observe "org.jboss.seam.createProcess" to get all createProcess events.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the if, you must write super.raiseEvent(...) otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Voted down, may seem harsh but it pains me to see a new(ish) user getting rep for posting an answer that should have been a comment.

Comment: Yes this should have been a comment

Comment: @Simon Gibbs new users can't comment everywhere, you need at least 50 reputation for that privilege.